# Is it possible to get one row by grouping more than one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query as below. DB from http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

```
SELECT count(distinct C.CustomerID),C.Country 
FROM Customers C
inner join Orders O
on C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
inner join OrderDetails D
on O.OrderID  = D.OrderID 
inner join Products P
on D.ProductID = P.ProductID
group by C.Country,P.CategoryID
order by C.Country
```

Here is the result from above.
[image]

But I want to get one row per country(as below pic) by counting CustomerIDs where any CustomerIDs are in the same country and have a same CategoryID as well. So I have to group by 2 columns. Is there any way to do it? Could you please kindly suggest me?

[image]
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's quite simple. Just remove `P.CategoryID` in your `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT C.CustomerID), C.Country
FROM Customers C
INNER JOIN Orders O
  ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
INNER JOIN OrderDetails D
  ON O.OrderID = D.OrderID
INNER JOIN Products P
  ON D.ProductID = P.ProductID
GROUP BY C.Country
ORDER BY C.Country;
```

#### Update

Following your comment, this should be correct approach then:

```
SELECT T.Country, SUM(T.Cnt)
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT C.CustomerID) AS Cnt, C.Country
  FROM Customers C
  INNER JOIN Orders O
    ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
  INNER JOIN OrderDetails D
    ON O.OrderID = D.OrderID
  INNER JOIN Products P
    ON D.ProductID = P.ProductID
  GROUP BY C.Country, P.CategoryID
  ) AS T
GROUP BY T.Country
ORDER BY T.Country;
```

Comment: But I want to count customerIDs that have the same CategoryID and same Country.

Comment: @Pizza I've updated my answer. It should be correct now. But for the sake of interest, could you tell me what's the result with first query? I don't have access to your data.